# how to get equality behavior with autoboxing comparing with Object and int as Java 7 with Java8

Tags: java, autoboxing

We have code that needs to upgrade from Java 7 to Java 8.
Lot's of snippets like this:

```
public class TestJava8 {

    private static void TestIntegerConversion(){
        Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println(m.get("status") != 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] argvs){
        TestIntegerConversion();
    }
}
```

We have take advantage that `m.get("status") != 0` returns `false` only if **there is a int value number for key "status"** and **it's not 0**. If the "status" is 0 or omited, it will return `true`. which is the desired behavior.

But when upgrading to Java 8 it will complain that  `incomparable types: java.lang.Object and int` error, and if we do a force cast `(int)m.get("status")` there will be an Exception instead of return `true` when `"status"`was omitted.

So is there an equality behavior trick that could make equality behavior like Java 7?

Comment: How about using [`getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-)?

Comment: You might get away by replacing `0` with `Integer.valueOf(0)` , but I'd  suggest to get rid of that "advantage", which rather indicates unclean use of (auto)boxing, BTW never compare `Integer` instances using `==`, rather use `equals()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flip the condition around, and check against the boxed Integer:

```
!Integer.valueOf(0).equals(m.get("status"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static utility function which explicitly does what you need.
It would also be helpful if you ever need to change this status logic globally.

```
/**
 * Returns true if value is null or a non-integer or a non-zero integer.
*/
public static boolean isNonZeroOrMissingStatusValue(final Object value) {
    return !isZeroStatusValue(value);
}

/**
 * Returns true if value is an integer zero.
*/
public static boolean isZeroStatusValue(final Object value) {
    return (value instanceof Integer) // this will be false if value is null
        && ((Integer) value).intValue() == 0;
}

...

private static void TestIntegerConversion(){
    Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
    System.out.println(isNonZeroOrMissingStatusValue(m.get("status")));
}
```